# Bootstrap Close accordion menu's

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am new to bootstrap, and created a navigation menu using bootstrap accordion. When I click on any link it's opening the accordion but not closing the opened accordion. How can I achieve that ?

I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4qk86/

my accordion code is:

```
<li>
        <div class="accordion-heading "> <a href="#accDash" data-parent="#mainSideMenu" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle"> 
                                        <span class="item-icon fontello-icon-monitor"></span> 
                                        <i class="chevron fontello-icon-right-open-3"></i> Dashboards 
                                    </a> 
        </div>
        <ul class="accordion-content nav nav-list collapse in" id="accDash">
            <li class="active"> <a href="dashboard-one.html"> 
                                            <i class="fontello-icon-right-dir"></i> 
                                            <span class="hidden-tablet">Dashboard</span> Demo 1 
                                        </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="dashboard-two.html"> 
                                            <i class="fontello-icon-right-dir"></i> 
                                            <span class="hidden-tablet">Dashboard</span> Demo 2 
                                        </a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Please take the time to properly display your code, so other users can easily read it. Currently, it is extremely difficult to read your code.

Answer (score 1):

The bit of code in your JSFiddle works correctly: the accordion menus expand and collapse when they are clicked on. Maybe there is a problem elsewhere in your site's code that is preventing this. Usually making sure that your jQuery code is within `$(document).ready();` solves problems with correct code that won't run.

Comment: But I want to close first accordion if the user clicks on 2nd

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap API page says you should specify the data-parent attribute. Then, try to add data-parent="accDash" to you  elements.

See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example from the Bootstrap [site](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) (shortened to only have two panels). Basically, the outer div is given an id, say `id="accordion"` and to make the accordion effect (where when you open another collapsible element, the current one closes), you set `data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"` for each heading.

On the other hand, if you want to make each collapsible panel independent of each other, so that more than one panel can be open at a time, just change it to `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="collapseOne"` where `collapseOne` refers to the id of the panel that clicking on the heading opens. (So the next panel will reference `collapseTwo`, for example).

Here's the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shimizust/m32hQ/) as well to play around with.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        First collapsible panel
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Second collapsible panel
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```